# Errors after installing typescript-vim on vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have installed typescript-vim on my MacOsx like on this instruction:

```
git clone https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim.git ~/.vim/plugged/typescript-vim
```

I have placed this code in the `.vimrc` file:

```
Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
```

Then:

```
:PlugInstall
```

So plugin has bee installed, but when I open any file in vim I get the errors:

```
Error detected while processing FileType Autocommands for "typescript":

E492: Not an editor command: JsPreTmpl html
```

(After pressing ENTER command I can continue work)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce an error like this by invoking the `:JsPreTmpl html` command from [vim-js-pretty-template](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-js-pretty-template) in a Vim buffer, without having that plugin installed in my Vim bundle.

Check out `.vimrc` or `.vimrc.local`-- I'm guessing you'll see the line `autocmd FileType javascript JsPreTmpl html`. If that's true, you have two options to make this error go away: remove the autocommand, or install the plugin.

https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-js-pretty-template